# How to color individual parts of curve in unity, real time?

Tags: unity, c#, color, mesh

So I have a mesh curve that I've imported from Blender. What I want to do is to place individual points on the curve (at fixed distance) and then based on a specific number, color them.

Let's say for instance number 1000 is color red and number 10 is color blue (based on color gradient). These numbers get updated real time, so I want my color to get updated real time.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I've looked up some ideas but couldn't find anything useful.

Please help!

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Does your mesh have UV coordinates generated? Have you looked at modifying the [vertex colors](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html)?

Comment: How are you placing the points?  If they are unity prefabs, you could just update their color in the update() by having some variable that it reads from.